# Is there a Python port for the new FB Messenger webhook?

Tags: facebook, webhooks, facebook-messenger

Couldn't find anything in python for FB Messenger webhook quickstart page. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart)

Answer (score 3):

I went ahead and ported it myself. Figured I should share the riches. This snippet response to every message with " to you!":

```
import json
import requests
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

FB_MESSENGER_ACCESS_TOKEN = "<Your Access Token>"


def respond_FB(sender_id, text):
    json_data = {
        "recipient": {"id": sender_id},
        "message": {"text": text + " to you!"}
    }
    params = {
        "access_token": FB_MESSENGER_ACCESS_TOKEN
    }
    r = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages', json=json_data, params=params)
    print(r, r.status_code, r.text)

#this allows the requst to come in without requiring CSRF token
@csrf_exempt
def fb_webhook(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        if (request.GET.get('hub.verify_token') == 'this_is_a_verify_token_created_by_sean'):
            return HttpResponse(request.GET.get('hub.challenge'))
        return HttpResponse('Error, wrong validation token')

    if request.method == "POST":
        body = request.body
        print("BODY", body)
        messaging_events = json.loads(body.decode("utf-8"))
        print("JSON BODY", body)
        sender_id = messaging_events["entry"][0]["messaging"][0]["sender"]["id"]
        message = messaging_events["entry"][0]["messaging"][0]["message"]["text"]
        respond_FB(sender_id, message)
        return HttpResponse('Received.')
```

[And here is the FB Messenger Chatbot port on Gist](https://gist.github.com/sshadmand/304a77371c9e207a5fa42a6b874017d5)

Comment: Thanks so much Sean! What would be the `urllib` equivalent for `r = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages', json=json_data, params=params)`?

Comment: This site http://buddylindsey.com/basic-urllib-get-and-post-with-and-without-data/ offers some info on the subject. I suspect the final code would look something like this: 

data = urllib.urlencode(json_data);
u = urllib.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages? access_token=[access_token]", data);

Comment: Thank you! I am running the code on GAE so can't use `requests`. I used the code you pointed to and it's somehow resulting in a `Bad Request 400`. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have "https://" in the url (got cut out for some reason in SO edit.) Also, make sure you have the correct access_token and pass the correct sender:id.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a Python client for Facebook Messenger Platform: [messengerbot](https://github.com/geeknam/messengerbot)

Answer (score 1):

This is the python sample using [fbmq library](https://github.com/conbus/fbmq) that works for me:

echo example :

```
from flask import Flask, request
from fbmq import Page

page = fbmq.Page(PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
  page.handle_webhook(request.get_data(as_text=True))
  return "ok"

@page.handle_message
def message_handler(event):
  page.send(event.sender_id, event.message_text)
```